# Object reference not set to an instance of an object work around

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.ios

I am building a BLE app in Xamain.Forms. I am using an adapter which triggers a number of methods based on events, for example `adapter.DeviceDiscovered` etc. The process goes:

1. Scan for Devices
2. Connect to chosen device
3. Scan for `Services` present on device
4. Select a `Service`
5. Scan for `Characteristics` on device

I am working on step 5 now and have the following code:

```
ChosenService.CharacteristicsDiscovered += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    Debug.WriteLine("service.CharacteristicsDiscovered");
    if (characteristics.Count == 0)
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            foreach (var characteristic in ChosenService.Characteristics) {
                characteristics.Add(characteristic);
            }
        });
};
```

However, as `ChosenService` is null until step 4 is complete, on the opening of the app, this method throws a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception. How can I work around this? Ideally, I suppose I need to read the method after I have set `ChosenService`, how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/activity_lifecycle/) to see if there is a state that will do what you want
If not, consider using Tasks and settings procedures to run after a complete of a task

```
LoadData().ContinueWith(task => {
     BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
         _myData = task.Result;
         // Do Some UI stuff or something else
     });
}
```

Check more about `Tasks` and `.ContinueWith` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, there isn't an app lifecycle which does this. for me. I am broadly familiar with Tasks, however, don't have much experience with them. How would you suggest I implement this?

Comment: After the function that populate `ChosenService` with `CharacteristicsDiscovered` run your code like in the code i have post, please update your question with more code (where is this code that must be implemented first?) in order to be more accurate